# meaning of the grammar structure "coming as one do/did"?

Tags: grammar

I have come across it in [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/oPf27gAup9U). It is at 3 minute and 4 second. Here it goes:

> **Coming as he did** from the senatorial class, it was natural that Caesar would serve in both the army and the Senate, which he did.

I feel that the part *as he did* could mean *it is actually true*, but I am confused because of the word *as*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand **coming as he did** to be a kind of do-emphasis with ellipsis of the infinitive: **coming as he did [come]**.

Compare the emphatic here:

> As you *do* know, Mr O'Hope, this class starts at 9AM on the dot.

**as** could be paraphrased "in the way (that), in the manner (that), like".

**as he did** is an adjunct to the predicate which also identifies the subject of the predication. Without it, there would be a non-finite clause without a subject:

Coming from the senatorial class...

and then a possible parsing hiccup when we reach **it**, the grammatical subject of **was** in the main clause, which stands in for the *that*-clause, which supplies the idea-content for **it**.

but with **as he did**, there is a clearer connection between the non-finite clause and the matrix clause:  **he** = **Caesar**.

We can turn the sentence around and eliminate the dummy **it**:

> That Caesar would serve as he did in both the army and the Senate was
>   only natural, for he came from the senatorial class.

And in that rewrite, **as he did** = **as he did [serve]**.

The *that*-clause without **as he did** would not declare a fact about Caesar. It declares only a possible idea; it is only a nominal, not a predicate, hence the need for **as he did**.

> That everyone on the planet should have food to eat ...

does not contain a predicate. **That** turns it into a nominal, which can be the subject of a predicate.

> That Caesar would serve — as he did in fact serve — in both the army and the Senate was only natural, for he came from the senatorial class.

Without **as he did** the *that*-clause could be paraphrased as

> That Caesar *was expected to serve* in both the army and the Senate ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that we are not talking in this case of an specific structure "coming as one do/did"

Let me rephrase your sentence

> Coming from the senatorial class, as he did, it was natural that
>   Caesar would serve in both the army and the Senate, which he did.

The adverb **as** alone is - according to Google Translator -

> used in **comparisons** to refer to the extent or degree of something.

Your phrase is establishing a **comparison** between those who **come** from the senatorial class and Caesar, indicating that Caesar was their equal, that he **did** belong to that class.

I don't see an explicit "it is actually true" remark there.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the wrong answer by accident. Clicked on the wrong link.

Comment: No problem. I was just asking myself, why he doesn't edit his own post?XD